# Same flash file links not working on different websites

Tags: html, flash

Hello i have embedded same flash file into two sites but link not working as the first one.

First website : 
  `http://www.1.asianhighway26.com/phil.swf`

Here you can see a red line and if you click that it will redirect you to another page.

2nd website: `http://orlandojoes.co.uk/map.php`

Here you can see the same red line and you are not going to a link by clicking on that link

So where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The link inside the SWF (inside the PHP page) is not working because you didn't allow that SWF to access to any script other than ones from the same domain using the `allowScriptAccess` parameter set to `sameDomaine`.

So to get your external link working, you have to use `allowScriptAccess` set to `always`, like this for example :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="532" height="700" id="phil" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.1.asianhighway26.com/phil.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.1.asianhighway26.com/phil.swf" width="532" height="700">
        <param name="movie" value="phil.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    </object>
</object>
```

Try to use `<object>` instead of `<embed>` and don't forget to set the same SWF's URL in the both `<object>` tags.

For more details about `allowScriptAccess`, take a look on [control access to scripts](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html).

Hope that can help.